# C: File locking between threads

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, file-locking

I have written below code where the server is getting requests from clients on socket and creating a thread per client. Each client thread is then writing to a file which is common to all the threads. The file has been `open`ed when main starts, so the same fd is being used by each thread. In such a scenario I have tried to achieve locking on file when one thread is writing to it. Since the threads are of same process so `flock` can't simply lock the file, hence `mutex` is used.

```
/*Logging function*/
void write_to_file(int op_fd,char *name)
{
   flock(op_fd,LOCK_EX);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&f_lck);
      write(op_fd,name,20);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&f_lck);
   flock(op_fd,LOCK_UN);
}

/*Client thread function*/

void *clnt_thread(void * arg)
{
  int this_fd=*(int *)arg;
  /*str is a continuous memory array of the size of the dat_com struct.This will be filled up initially on receive as a normal array
   , but then it'll typecasted to point to struct dat_com object*/
  char str[sizeof(dat_com)],str_send[25];

  memset(&str,'\0',sizeof(str));
  dat_com *incm_dat;    // struct to contain the incoming data from client .

  while(1)
  {
  read(this_fd,str,sizeof(str));
  /*typecast to struct dat_com so that it is ready to be inserted into linked list or file.*/
  incm_dat=(dat_com *)&str;

   if(strncmp(str,"quit",4)==0)
    break;

  /*Call write to file function*/
  write_to_file(o_fd,incm_dat->name);
  fprintf(stderr,"Client said: %s",incm_dat->name);

  /*client wants to close connection?*/

  sprintf(str_send,"%s",incm_dat->name);
  send(this_fd,str_send,sizeof(incm_dat->name),MSG_NOSIGNAL);
  }
close(this_fd);
return 0;
}
```

This is working as expected at the moment. Is this a good practice to lock this way? or is there any other best practice? If I have to put this code on production what changes I'd need to make that are not standard practice?
I understand this should ideally be on `codereview` site,so I've already posted it there 3 days back but haven't got any comments.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, it is not a very good practice to give each writing thread a direct access to the file descriptor. I think it would be better to create a file writer proxy that manages and governs all writes to the file, and pass that proxy to each client. You can then set up queue mechanisms between the client threads and the file proxy (on its own thread probably) thus separating the client objects from the writing to file logic and handling completely and maintaining better encapsulation.

Comment: Is this proxy thing something standard term? Sorry but not aware of this term so would like to ask what that proxy will be.. a separate function for a separate managing thread?

Comment: @Diwakar Sharma Sorry, for some reason I didn't notice that you are using pure C and not an object oriented language so that is not really applicable in your case. My bad.